# Function loads faster than layout in Android

Tags: android

I developed an android app to record sound from microphone, it has 2 activities, in first activity there is a pic, when user touch the pic the app should run the secound activty to record sound, my problem is by touching the picture, second xml layout dose not apeare until the record done, I mean by clicking picture it starts to record when it finishes then second layout appeares. I want the app by clicking pic it shows me the next layout and then the record function runs. here is my code, Is asynctask helpful?

Main:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView micro = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    micro.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Record.class));
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Record:

```
public class Record extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
String name;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.record);

    record();

}

public void record() {
    .
    . 
    .
  }
}
```

Comment: you can add the `record();` statement in `onResume` method.But smartest one would be using a new thread(AsyncTask,Handler etc.)

Comment: I think asynctask is helpful but I do not know how to use it

Comment: then search for it, plenty of tuts out there :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, move the `mp = new MediaPlayer();` into the `onCreate()`

also don't forget to add:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

Comment: still having same problem

Comment: try adding this: 
`@Override public void onResume(){ record(); }`
to your Record activity

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
     public class Record extends Activity {

            MediaPlayer mp;
            String name;

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.record);
                mp = new MediaPlayer();
                 new LongOperation().execute();

            }
            private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
               {
                  @Override
                  protected void doInBackground(String... params) { 

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                          @Override
                            public void run() {
                            // add code for record here.
                            }
                        });
                  }      
               }
        }
```

Comment: Hey amir , have you try this. if not working then also please reply we can solve this using Thread also.

Comment: still having same problem

Comment: it makes this error: `android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` I think asynctask can help but I do not know how to use

Comment: it causes this error for execute in `LongOperation().execute("");` `is not applicable for the arguments(String)`

Comment: try LongOperation().execute();

Comment: I got this error while attemptong to run record `Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views`

Answer (score 0):

Just move your call of `record()` into `onWindowFocusChanged()` method

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
{
    record(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call record() on a separate (non-UI) thread, preferably using an AsyncTask. doInBackground will contain the record call.